# Correspondence between fractional ideals of $K$ and invertible sheaves of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal O_K$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, schemes

In Vakil's FOAG, it is an exercise to show that if $K$ is a number field and $\mathfrak a\subseteq K$ is a fractional ideal, then $\mathfrak a$ determines an invertible sheaf of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathcal O_K$, where $\mathcal O_K$ denotes the ring of integers of $K$.

My first thought is to just take $\mathcal L=\widetilde{\mathfrak a}$, but this doesn't seem to be locally trivial. I would need to show that there exists a generating set $\{\alpha_i\}$ of $\mathcal O_{K}$ such that $\mathfrak a_{\alpha_i}\cong(\mathcal O_K)_{\alpha_i}$ as $(\mathcal O_K)_{\alpha_i}$-modules. The latter condition is equivalent to there existing some $n\ge0$ such that $\alpha_i^n\in\mathfrak a$.

None of what I'm saying is in any way using the defining property of fractional ideals, i.e. that there exists some $\alpha\in\mathcal O_K$ such that $\alpha\mathfrak a\subseteq\mathcal O_K$. It seems like this problem should be simple, but I don't see how to do it. Can anybody possibly suggest something to guide me in the right direction?

Comment: The condition that there is some $n$ with $\alpha_i^n\in\mathfrak{a}$ is equivalent to the condition that the inclusion $\mathfrak{a}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{O}_K$ induces an isomorphism $\mathfrak{a}_{\alpha_i}\cong(\mathcal{O}_K)_{\alpha_i}$. To conclude $\mathfrak{a}$ is locally trivial, we just need there to be some isomorphism (not necessarily induced by inclusion).

Comment: @JulianRosen ah, yeah I see the difference now. So really what I need to show is that $\mathfrak a_{\alpha_i}$ is generated over $(\mathcal O_K)_{\alpha_i}$ by a single element if I make the proper choice of $\alpha_i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fractional part is meaningless, since multiplication by a scalar
is an isomorphism onto its image, so every fractional ideal is
isomorphic as a module to some ideal. To me, the most geometric way to
think about this is to introduce the notion of "order of vanishing" of
an element at a prime ideal (geometrically, of a function at a point),
which amounts to showing that the local rings are discrete valuation rings.
Then you can get your $\alpha_i$ as follows: given a prime $\mathfrak{p}$, let $f$ be an element of your ideal with minimal order of vanishing at $\mathfrak{p}$.

Exercise: There is some $\alpha$ not in $\mathfrak{p}$ such that after inverting $\alpha$, $f$ generates your ideal (just throw away the other points where $f$ vanishes).

Answer (score 0):

*Just to add some details to the accepted answer:*

Clearly, it suffices to treat the case of an integral ideal $I=P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r}$ inside $\mathcal{O}_K$, where $e_1,\dots,e_r\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}$ and $P_i$ are distinct maximal ideals.

For any given prime ideal $Q$ that is not one of $P_i$, there is an element $f\in \bigcap_{i=1}^r P_i \setminus Q$ because $Q$ is prime.
That is, $Q\in D(f)$ and every $P_i$ contains $f$, in which case $I_f=(P_1)_f^{e_1}\cdots (P_r)_f^{e_r}=(\mathcal{O}_K)_f$.

For one of $P_i$, say $P_1$, there is an element in $f \in \bigcap_{i=2}^r P_i \setminus P_1$ because $P_1$ is prime. Then, $P_1\in D(f)$ and $(P_i)_f = (\mathcal{O}_K)_f$ for $i\geq 2$. We know that $P_1$ is a finitely generated ideal, and its localization at itself ${P_1}_{P_1}$ is principal in $(\mathcal{O}_{K})_{P_1}$. Inverting another element $g\in \mathcal{O}_K \setminus P_1$ such that a principal generator $\pi$ of ${P_1}_{P_1}$ appears in $(P_1)_{fg}$ and such that each element in a finite set of generators of $P_1$ is an $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{fg}$-multiple of $\pi$, we see that $I_{fg}$ is generated by $\pi$ as an $(\mathcal{O}_K)_{fg}$-module, and hence $\widetilde{I}|_{D(fg)}\simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathrm{Spec} (\mathcal{O}_K)_{fg}}$.

Therefore, a fractional ideal of $K$ can be seen as a locally free sheaf of rank $1$ on $\mathrm{Spec} \mathcal{O}_K$.